# scikit cosine_similarity vs pairwise_distances

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn

What is the difference between Scikit-learn's sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity and sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances(.. metric="cosine")?

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

documents = (
    "Macbook Pro 15' Silver Gray with Nvidia GPU",
    "Macbook GPU"    
)

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)

from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
print(cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix[0:1], tfidf_matrix)[0,1])
```

0.37997836

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances
print(pairwise_distances(tfidf_matrix[0:1], tfidf_matrix, metric='cosine')[0,1])
```

0.62002164

Why are these different?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From source code [documentation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py):

```
Cosine distance is defined as 1.0 minus the cosine similarity.
```

So your result make sense.

Comment: Um wow. Yes. That makes a lot of sense - can't believe I missed that

Comment: Six years later this has had over 10,000 views so I guess I wasn't the only one who missed it!

Answer (score 1):

pairwise distance provide distance between two array.so more pairwise distance means less similarity.while cosine similarity is 1-pairwise_distance so more cosine similarity means more similarity between two arrays.